# Short hand for number of tags having lengthier [and almost same] Xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

For example : this is an xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/root/sub-root/parent/child/grand_child/dummy1/dummy2/dummy3/dummy4/node_1
|/root/sub-root/parent/child/grand_child/dummy1/dummy2/dummy3/dummy4/node_2
|/root/sub-root/parent/child/grand_child/dummy1/dummy2/dummy3/dummy4/node_3
 .
 .
|/root/sub-root/parent/child/grand_child/dummy1/dummy2/dummy3/dummy4/node_N"/>
```

In the above code can I use the XPath
`/root/sub-root/parent/child/grand_child/dummy1/dummy2/dummy3/dummy4`
only once [use the braces or whatever] and reduce the bulkiness of the code?

As you can see, all the nodes are siblings of each-other, so except their name their Xpath is same. Is there any short-hand property ?

Does XSLT 1.0 (or Xpath1.0) allows it?

Comment: Good question again, @infant programmer (+1). You rarely need to specify in a match pattern the complete path to a node -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only tested it in an online xpath tool, so not entirely sure, but it should work

```
<xsl:template match="/root/sub-root/parent/child/grand_child/dummy1/dummy2/dummy3/dummy4/node()[name() = 'node_1' or name()='node_2' ... or name()='node_N']"/>
```

If there aren't any nodes in dummy4 you want to omit, just drop the [..]

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself if the long specific match expression is really necessary. I see that this is an example only, but you don't really have to include the *complete path* to the element, only as much as necessary to make it unambiguous.

Further, I remind you of the `self` axis:

```
<xsl:template match="/.../dummy4/*[self::node_1 or self::node_2 ...]" />
```

If the name is structured and predictable, you can do

```
<xsl:template match="/.../dummy4/*[substring-before(name(), '_') = 'node']" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does XSLT 1.0 (or Xpath1.0) allows it?

**The following is a correct XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
root/sub-root/parent/child/grand_child
              /dummy1/dummy2/dummy3/dummy4
                /*
                 [starts-with(name(), 'node_')
                and
                  substring-after(name(), 'node_') >= 1
                and
                  not(substring-after(name(), 'node_') > $N)
                  ]
```

**However, [match patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#patterns) are only a subset of all XPath expressions** and certain restrictions apply on them. In particular, *in XSLT 1.0 they cannot contain a reference to an xsl:variable*.

In case the value N is statically known, then one will substitute this literal value (say 1000) in the above XPath expression, and thus have a valid XSLT 1.0 match pattern.

**Do note that this is an extreme case** and it is extremely unlikely in any practical circumstances to need such a long match pattern. By definition, a match pattern doesn't need to specify the complete path to the node -- only a sufficient "from-right-subpath" that disambiguates the node from other nodes with the same name that must be processed by a different template.

**So, in most cases even the following will be sufficient**:

```
 *
 [starts-with(name(), 'node_')
and
  substring-after(name(), 'node_') >= 1
and
   not(substring-after(name(), 'node_') > {N})

 ]
```

where {N} must be replaced by a integer literal -- the actual value of $N.

**Or, in the easiest case (happens quite often), if there are four nodes and no disambiguation is necessary**, one would just use:

```
 node_1|node_2|node_3|node_4
```

Comment: what if the node names aren't identical? I mean node_1, node_2 are just examples .. in typical example I will not be having them ..

Comment: @infant-programmer, then you need to have all of the possible elements' names in a separate structure, and compare the name of eac element being processed with the names from this structure. Tyoically, we are talking about having a separate "lookup file". This becomes another question, you may want to ask it. :)

Comment: No no, thanks, I think I never need it, suggestion by Ledhund is meeting my necessity all the way and you clarified many things too :) thanks :)